# Function to sum between 2 & 4 (DEFAULT ARGUMENTS)

Tags: function, arguments, default

Write a function that, using default arguments, allows user to take the sum of anywhere between 2 and 4 integers. THIS IS MY CODE SO FAR..

```
void sum(float a,float b);  
float sum(int a,int b, int c = 0);      
double sum(double a, double b, double c = 0, double d = 0);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int no[4];

    cout<< "Enter any number from 2 to 4: "<<endl;

    //Loop until EOF
    for(int i=0; no[i] != EOF; i++){
       cout<< ">> ";
       cin>> no[i]; //Ask value array no[]
       i++;
       }
      cout<<endl; 
      sum(no[0],no[1]);
      sum(no[0],no[1],no[2]);
    sum(no[0],no[1],no[2],no[3]); //call function

    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
    //FUNCTION
    int sum(int a, int b){
         cout<< a + b;
         }       
    float sum(int a, int b, int c){ 
         cout<< a + b + c;
         }       
    double sum(double a, double b, double c, double d){     
         cout<< a + b + c + d;
         }
```

Comment: EOF is generally used for reading files, why don't you just loop till 4 when you have explicitly declared that.. and try to reuse the old sum calculated...

Comment: Thanks for the reply Aura but how can i reuse the old sum array to recalculate?